# LNK1104: cannot open file 'glut32.lib'

Tags: cuda, glut

I am using "CUDA bu Example" book to get started with CUDA.
But when I included all header files given by book then  got ERROR as

Error   1  error LNK1104: cannot open file 'glut32.lib' D:\book\book\LINK   book

I am using Visual Studio 10
Please help me out of this

Comment: I solved this problem by copying glut32.lib file in my project..Thanks

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate more on your solution? Where in your project did you copy it to?

Answer (score 3):

I found the same error while setting it up in Visual Studio 2010

However, I also found a fix and wanted to share it.

Just copy and paste the glut32.lib file to MicrosoftSDKs folder, as this is the default location of VC++ linker location. To be exact

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib`

Comment: thanks your suggestion worked like a charm... I got another way. In
Property Pages-> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General
add your library's directory to "Additional Library Directories" field. worked for me

Comment: Or use Property Pages -> Configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories -> Library Directories and add your directory over there. Not really sure what the differences are with @SZaman 's approach.

Comment: I downloaded the glut 3.7, extracted it and added it as a lib directory like you mentioned above. but it didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to build the "shrUtils_vs2010.sln" solution if you haven't done it.
The file is in "\path_to_SDK\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.2\shared" folder.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the glut32.lib file from the lib folder in "cuda by example" to the folder below:

C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.5\lib\Win32

Comment: After doing that on Windows 10, I got a new error message saying that glut DLLs were missing - fixed that by copying glut64.dll to ...\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.1\bin. Finally works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this solution and it worked for me in *visual studio 2015*

> **1:** Copy *glut32.dll* to your project directory (where your `source.cpp` is)
>    **2:** Copy *glut.h* to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Vc\Include\gl` (*gl* folder should be created manually)
>    **3:** Copy *glut32.lib* to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Vc\lib` done.